# QGroupBox in Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am programming an interface in Python, using Pyqt5.

My program shows an interface with different boxes as shown below:

[image]

I want to put all of this inside a "QGroupBox", but I don't know how to do it

```
import sys, re
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMessageBox, QErrorMessage, QToolTip, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel, QTextEdit, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import ctypes

class Dialogo (QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.initUI()
     
    def initUI(self):

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
    
        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')
        self.setGeometry(700, 320, 500, 480)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Buscar', self)
        self.btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        self.btn.move(50, 50)
        self.btn.setGeometry(190,70,75,23)

        self.goodintransit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.goodintransit.setGeometry(175,40,110,20)
        self.label = QLabel('NP',self)
        self.label.setGeometry(215,20,110,20)

        self.yearmonth= QTextEdit(self)
        self.yearmonth.setGeometry(30,180,110,50)
        self.label = QLabel ('Año Mes', self)
        self.label.setGeometry (60,150, 150,30)
        
        self.gac = QTextEdit(self)
        self.gac.setGeometry(330,180,110,50)
        self.label= QLabel('Gac',self)
        self.label.setGeometry(365,150,110,30)
        
        self.purch = QTextEdit(self)
        self.purch.setGeometry(30,270,110,50)
        self.label= QLabel('Purch',self)
        self.label.setGeometry(50,245, 150,30)

        self.fechattdte= QTextEdit(self)
        self.fechattdte.setGeometry(180,180,110,50)
        self.label= QLabel('Fecha TTDTE',self)
        self.label.setGeometry(200,150, 150,30)
        
        self.key= QTextEdit(self)
        self.key.setGeometry(180,270,150,50)
        self.label= QLabel('Llave',self)
        self.label.setGeometry(200,245, 150,30)
        
    def closeEvent (self,event):
        resultado = QMessageBox.question(self, "Salir", "¿Seguro que quieres salir de la aplicación?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if resultado == QMessageBox.Yes: event.accept()
        else: event.ignore()
 

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialogo = Dialogo()
dialogo.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "theoretically" simple solution would be to create the group box as a child of the main window, and all children as child of that group box:

```
    def initUI(self):
        groupBox = QGroupBox(self)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Buscar', groupBox)
        self.goodintransit = QLineEdit(groupBox)
        # ...
```

But this is **not** the correct solution, and for two reasons:

1. all widgets that are going to be inside a QMainWindow (except for the menubar, toolbars, dock widgets and the status bar) should not be direct children of it, but children of a main *central widget* (read more on the [Qt Main Window Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) documentation);
2. you should not use fixed geometries, but prefer [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead;

```
    def initUI(self):

        self.groupBox = QGroupBox('My group')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.groupBox)

        # create a layout and automatically set it for the group box
        layout = QGridLayout(self.groupBox)

        self.label = QLabel('NP',self)
        self.goodintransit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Buscar')
        # add widgets to the *second* column
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.goodintransit, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 2, 1)

        self.yearmonth_label = QLabel('Año Mes')
        self.yearmonth = QTextEdit(self)
        # add widgets to the first column, from the *fourth* row
        layout.addWidget(self.yearmonth_label, 3, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.yearmonth, 3, 0)

        # ...
```

As you can see, I removed all calls to `move()` or `setGeometry()` (also, calling calling `move()` before `setGeometry()` is useless, as setting a geometry implies a movement). That's because whenever a QWidget becomes managed by a layout, its geometry is completely controlled by the layout, and any attempt to manually change the geometry will be ignored or overridden at the next resize event.

Do note that continuously overwriting an attribute as you did with `self.label` makes it completely useless (and can potentially lead to the previous object being deleted). Instance attributes should be set only when it is required that they persist outside the scope of the function in which they are created (normally in order to be able to access them externally/from other functions), and should be overwritten only when the previous object is not required anymore.
If you need to keep a reference to those labels (for example, to change their text), use *unique* names, as I did for the `yearmonth_label` above; otherwise, use a local variable instead.